# Como crear un formulario en visual studios 2019 sin que me de el errorintellisense error 0x80131509 a la hora de agregar formularios en carpetas?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber como solucionarlo?

Comment: veo la direccion de las carpetas muy larga, proba cambiar a una direccion anterior. es lo unico que se me ocurre, y proba compilar antes.

Comment: Lo intentare a ver si es eso. Aunque no creo por que lo había hecho con varios proyectos y este es el único. Que me da problemas con los formularios.